# Как определить момент завершения фонового потока?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Создал Windows-приложение, состоящее из двух форм. На первой форме осуществляется запуск второй. Есть один нюанс. Перед запуском второй формы, происходит копирование файлов, которые потом будут задействованы во второй форме. Дело в том, что во время этого действия первая форма полностью зависает. Поэтому я решил использовать многопоточность. Для работы с файлами я создал новый фоновый поток. Мне необходимо **определить время его завершения**, чтобы запустить вторую форму, поскольку если я включу запуск второй формы в тот же поток, что и работа с файлами, то он выдаст исключение:

> "Создание экземпляра элемента управления ActiveX "8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2" невозможно: текущий поток не находится в однопоточном контейнере."

Что мне посоветуете?

Comment: @VladD разве не может быть [tag:wpf]?

Comment: @alexolut: «Windows-приложение, состоящее из двух _форм_». Это Winforms-специфичная терминология. Ну и прямое использование ActiveX-контролов (в данном случае AxWebBrowser) очень напоминает WinForms.

Comment: @alexolut: Хотя вы правы, это может быть и WPF-проблема. Уберу тег.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретный способ того, как уведомить главную форму о завершении потока, зависит от того, как поток был вызван. Например, если используется [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), который выполняет длительную операцию (копирование файлов), то он по завершении сигналит событием [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx#Y695). То есть, в вызывающей форме нужно повесить на событие обработчик: когда поток отработает, обработчик активируется и сможет запустить второй поток. По первой ссылке в MSDN есть понятный пример, как это правильно сделать.

Если поток вызывается как-то иначе, то, в любом случае, по его завершении можно сигналить событие вручную, а отлавливать его в главной форме.

Comment: Скажите, а можно в одном приложении использовать несколько BackgroundWorker'ов?

Comment: Можно. Каждый из них будет создавать свой фоновый поток, а события о прогрессе операции и о её завершении они будут прокидывать в поток пользовательского интерфейса.

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы проверить, работает поток или уже завершился, можно использовать свойство объекта Thread IsAlive. Для отслеживания этого момента я как-то сделал дополнительный фоновый поток (IsBackground = true), который в цикле с периодом 100 мс проверял, завершился ли интересующий нас поток, с помощью этого свойства. По завершении этого потока он выполнял определённые действия и сам завершался. Но тогда мне это нужно было для того, чтобы корректно завершить побочный поток при завершении главного; сам побочный поток делать фоновым было нельзя, так как он работал с файловой системой и требовал корректного завершения, а не молчаливого прерывания.

Кроме того, я могу предложить приём, позволяющий работать в однопоточном апартаменте вне зависимости от контекста вызова.

```
void Run(ThreadStart doSomething)
{
    if (doSomething == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("doSomething");

    if (Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() == ApartmentState.STA)
        doSomething();
    else
    {
        var th = new Thread(doSomething);

        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
        th.Join();
    }
}
```

То есть, если мы уже в однопоточном апартаменте, просто вызываем переданный через параметр делегат. Если нет, создаём новый поток в однопоточном апартаменте и ждём его завершения.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

На потоках можно ждать. WaitForSingleObject().

Comment: Это работает тогда, когда объект синхронизации известен потоку, завершения которого ожидает другой поток.